# Integer constraint getting dropped in VBA code (Solver)

Tags: vba, excel, integer, constraints, solver

I am trying to write a VBA code. I wish to restrict my variables to integers only (no decimals), for which I have added an integer constraint in my list of constraints. However, when I run the VBA code, somehow, ONLY the integer constraint gets dropped and rest stay intact. I tried running the solver by adding the integer constraint and it works like a charm. I would appreciate any help in this regard.

```
Solver reset
SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$13", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="0"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$J$12", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$J$24"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$J$12", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="-$G$4"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$J$12:$J$13", Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
```

Comment: What is your definition of "Integer constraint"? Can you re-write your question, so community is able to understand what you are asking for? Otherwise it's a clear *drop* on the way!

Comment: I totally agree with @bonCodigo! This is not a valid question unless serious editing would be made. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

The Help for `SolverAdd` function says

> Relation   Required Integer. The arithmetic relationship between the left and right sides of the constraint. If you choose 4 or 5, CellRef must refer to adjustable (changing) cells, and FormulaText should not be specified.

So, change the last line in your code sample from

```
SolverAdd CellRef:="$J$12:$J$13", Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
```

to

```
SolverAdd CellRef:="$J$12:$J$13", Relation:=4
```

The `FormulaText` parameter is optional and can (and should be for integer constraints) be left out.